# ImageButton change on pressed and click event

Tags: android, android-imageview

I want to have a design on my ImageButton like this...

ImageView1->Pressed->ImageView2->left->ImageView3->pressed->ImageView4->Left->ImageView1

I tried various combination of focused and pressed but was not successful. Can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: Yes, a lot of people can help you to do this. But no one can without seeing what you have tried

Comment: if you have proper naming convention followed then can do like img_1 clicked then use string tokenizer get value after '_' increment it and prepare like this imageName = "img_"+variable_value; then
use getResources().getIdentifier(imageName,"drawable", getPackageName()); This is a simple method. You will get image id with the above method then use imageView.setImageDrawable() method to update the image.

Comment: @kumar thanks for your comment but I cant get what you are trying to say, by the way I have got the solution for that and updated it in the answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
img.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
   if(flag==0){
       switch(event.getAction())
       {
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
             img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.Image2);
             break;
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
             flag=1;
             img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.Image3);
             break;
       }
    }else if(flag==1){
         switch(event.getAction())
         {
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.Image4);
                break;
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
                flag=0;
                img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.Image1);
         }
    }
  return false;
```

}
    });